# Genetic algorithm individual vs chromosome

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I am trying to understand genetic algorithm principles. I am following this [http://www.ai-junkie.com/ga/intro/gat2.html](http://geneticalgorithms.ai-depot.com/Tutorial/Overview.html) and this tutorial: [Second tutorial](http://geneticalgorithms.ai-depot.com/Tutorial/Overview.html). Both of these tutorials mention terms such as *individuals* and *chromosomes* in search space (a space where possible solutions are living).

When following the second tutorial, I somehow read from there that *individual* is actually same as *chromosome*. So is it true that actually solutions in a population are chromosomes? If so, why is even the term *individual* used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, they are often used interchangeably. However, some would say that the difference is like computer code vs the output of that code. A chromosome encodes an individual (but the individual is not a chromosome). Also like a genotype encodes a phenotype.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, based on this tutorial paper: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=538609

I have concluded that chromosome can be represented by genes of chromosome and gene is one part of chromosome. So to sum it up, individuals can be called as chromosomes as well.

I think I have made right conclusions.